# Change elements of matrix based on condition

Tags: matlab, if-statement, indexing

Suppose I have Matrix A:

```
A =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
```

For every element `x<2`, add 10,
for every element `x>5`, add 20, and
for every element `2<=x<=5`, add 30.

So for my example matrix A, I need to end up with the following matrix B:

```
B = 

11    32    33
34    35    26
```

I need to be able to do this in a general way, since the actual matrix will be quite large. Any suggestions? Can I use the `IF` statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need an `IF` you need [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html):

```
    IndexOfLessThan2 = A < 2;
    IndexOfGreaterThan5 = A > 5;
    IndexBtw2and5 = ~(IndexOfLessThan2 | IndexOfGreaterThan5);

    A = A + IndexOfLessThan2*10 + IndexOfGreaterThan5*20 + IndexBtw2and5*30;
```