# Classifying multivariate data and giving new coordinate

Tags: matlab, vector, coordinates

Consider a below data set

```
 Obs y x z
 1   3 10 1  
 2   0 12-1
 3   4  9 3
 4   2 15 0
```

y is a dependent variable and the others are explanatory variables

I want to give total 4 observations a new coordinates based on some conditions, for example,

If y is in [0,3) give 1 to that y,
or if y is in [3,6), give 2 to that y.

Likewise,
If x is in [9,12), give 1 to that x,
or if x is in [12,16), give 2 to that x,

And do the similar for z.

As a result,

```
Obs     y   x   z   coordinate

1       3   10  1   (1,1,1) 
2       0   12  1   (1,1,1)
3       4   9   3   (2,1,2)
4       2   15  0   (1,2,1)
```

I need these new coordinates as vectors for 4 observations.

I might be able to do this by 'loop' command, but it is too time consuming. 
So I need to do this without 'loop' but with some commands related to vector.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe if you told us how you calculate `coordinate` we could...

Comment: What do you mean by 'calculate coordinate'? I just give new coordinates to each observations as in three dimension.

Comment: I mean what you edited into the question after I commented.

Comment: So `y` is always between 0 and 6? `x` always between 9 and 16?

Comment: Note that your example coordinates don't match your rules. The first coordinate should be `(2,1,1)` (`[0,3)` means `>= 0` and `< 3`)

Comment: @ zelanix Thanks, It was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33570614/2433501) will work well if you only have two values for each coordinate based on a logical expression, if you have more complex logical requirements then I think that you want something similar to the following (which can easily be extended to cover more cases):

```
y = [ 3   0   4   2  ]';
x = [ 10  12  9   15 ]';
z = [ 1   1   3   0  ]';

coordinate = zeros(length(x), 3);

coordinate(y >= 0 & y < 3, 1) = 1;
coordinate(y >= 3 & y < 6, 1) = 2;

coordinate(x >= 9 & x < 12, 2) = 1;
coordinate(x >= 12 & x < 16, 2) = 2;

coordinate(z >= 0 & z < 3, 3) = 1;
coordinate(z >= 3 & z < 6, 3) = 2;

coordinate
```

results in

```
coordinate =

     2     1     1
     1     2     1
     2     1     2
     1     2     1
```

Where you can read each row off, for example `coordinate(1, :)` to get the first set of coordinates.

This also has the advantage that you can see where none of your rules match because the element in the `coordinate` matrix will be `0`. You could alternatively use `nan` instead of `zeros` to create the `coordinate` matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I never considered to put some conditions from other vector in the index of zero matrix, as you coded something like a 'A(y>1 & y<3, 1)'. When can I be like you?

Comment: @kurtkim Logical indexing in Matlab takes a while to get used to - it is quite different to anything available in most other programming language, where something like this would require a loop. Do it enough though, and you'll get used to it, and this is where Matlab becomes really powerful (although it is also easy to write very unreadable code this way). If this answer has helped you, please upvote / accept :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using logical indexing, in fact, this is pretty much answered here: [Change elements of matrix based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987313/change-elements-of-matrix-based-on-condition/11987344#11987344)

```
n=4;
coordinate = zeros(n,3);
%// y
coordinate(:,1) = (y > 3) + 1

%// x
coordinate(:,2) = (x > 12) + 1
```

etc...